# Big Cartel customizations

Tags: html

Big Cartel customer service suggested I might find answers to my questions here!

I want to add text to the collections (bands) pages. For example, on this page: https://www.perroowrecords.com/category/perseida, I want to add text below the word "Perseida". Is that possible at all?

Also, I want to add a different logo (from a sponsor) either on the top right corner of the main page, on the left side of the shopping cart logo, or at the bottom right of the main page, I'd like to delete the Big Cartel logo and replace it with the sponsor's logo. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Perroow, SO users have a high standard for questions, and it can be frustrating for new users. I recommend reading the SO guidelines. As for your question, please paste in the code you have tried and provide more context to what you are expecting it to do. This will yield more positive upvotes and answers.

Comment: Hi Bryan, you're right. I'll take some time to come up with a more detailed request. Thanks.